# Caching the AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, caching, xmlhttprequest

I used following to cache my ASP.NET page.

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
```

The problem is when I send AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) request from other page to this page, that response does not get cached on any browser but IE. (On IE, it gets cached even if I don't specify). How do I make it cache? Any client side solution? Thanks in advance...

Comment: similar question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650440/cache-ajax-requests

Comment: You may already know this, but it is important to ensure that your request is a GET and not a POST - most browsers will not cache POST requests regardless of the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer Links :

[Cache AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650440/cache-ajax-requests)

```
http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/05/high_performanc_2.html
http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_11.html
```

Expiring cache :

```
  header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=$seconds");
  header("Expires: ".gmdate('r', time()+$seconds));
```

I hppe it will help you.

Comment: But believe me... IE caches it even if you refresh... I've tested it with changed content... the only way through in that case is close the browser and start again...

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552710/how-best-to-work-with-the-expires-header-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question.. but I think you should do server-side caching instead of client-side caching for ajax requests.. if your botheration is performance on repeated ajax requests.. client-side caching has a lot of parameters based on the user and the browser types which is not an ideal place to depend on for caching.

Client-side cache, ideally, is for the user to set to increase his browsing performance independent of websites / web applications.

Comment: But how do I do it? that is what my question it. I am searching for a client side solution cause standard server side one didn't work for me.

Comment: For server-side caching: If you are using IIS 6 + for web server, you should be able to set 'Output caching' at iis config level itself for your web application. .. easiest approach without any code changes.

Answer (score -1):

you can add a dynamic querystring at the end of the url to get the unique data from ajax request each time.

so your url for ajax request could be like this:

```
var myUrl = "http://mysite.com/hello.aspx?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
```